# EXC_BAD_ACCESS When using fgets() and strtok()

Tags: c, file, csv, pthreads, fgets

my function (that is called by a pthread) either immediately gives me an EXC_BAD_ACCESS when entering the while loop or works properly for a few iterations before giving me EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

```
void* getImdbId(char* movieId, char** retImdb)
{
    FILE* imdbFile;
    char buffer[128];
    char* splitter;
    char* fMovId;
    char* imdbId;
    imdbFile = fopen("links.csv", "r");
    while(fgets(buffer, 127, imdbFile) != NULL){
            //Determine if movieID matches.
            splitter = strtok(buffer, ",");
            fMovId = splitter;
            splitter = strtok(NULL, ",");
            imdbId = splitter;
            puts(fMovId);
            puts(imdbId);
            if(strcmp(fMovId, movieId) == 0)
            {
                strcpy(*retImdb, imdbId);
                return 0;
            }
    }
}
```

links.csv contains two columns one with the movie id, and one with the imdbid.
I am getting both these values by using strtok (when it works properly for an iteration), and when it matches my parameter movieid it will modify the retImdb parameter for me to access in some of my other code, which also works properly when it does not error out on me.

Why is this happening?

Comment: You're not returning a value at the end of the function.  That will lead to problems eventually.  You don't close the file you opened before you return; you're leaking file streams.  You don't check that you opened the file successfully.  If it fails, you will crash (with EXC_BAD_ACCESS).  If you have `char buffer[128];` use 128 (not 127) in the call to `fgets()`, or pass `sizeof(buffer)` instead.  To debug, print the line you just read before you start splitting — to make sure you're getting data that looks like what you're expecting.

Comment: is `getImdbId` the function passed to `pthread_create`? If so, it has the wrong signature.

Comment: The best way to debug this is to use a debugger. It will tell you almost instantly exactly which line of code triggers the exception. And you can use the debugger to examine state and step the code line by line. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: regarding: `imdbFile = fopen("links.csv", "r");`  always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call `perror()` with your error message so both your error message AND the text reason the system thinks the error occurred are output to `stderr`

Comment: regarding: `while(fgets(buffer, 127, imdbFile) != NULL){`  1) use the actual size of the input buffer.  I.E. `while(fgets(buffer, sizeof( buffer ), imdbFile) != NULL){`  2) the function: `fgets()` also inputs/saves the newline into the input buffer, Suggest removing that with something similar to:  `buffer[ strcspn( buffer, "\n" ) ] = '\0';`

Comment: regarding: `splitter = strtok(buffer, ",");`  When calling `strtok()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: regarding: `void* getImdbId(char* movieId, char** retImdb)` and `return 0;`  the number 0 is not a pointer, Suggest using: `return NULL;`  Also, if a match is never found, the function fails to return anything specific.

Comment: the proper syntax for a thread function is: `void *functionName( void *arg );`  so the setting of a (non existent) parameter will fail.  Suggest `arg` be a pointer to a struct that contains the desired fields

Comment: in general, a thread function should be exited via the function call: `pthread_exit() with the parameter: `void *retValue`